# Android: Hide title bar while displaying split action bar in NarrowMode?

Tags: android, split, actionbarsherlock, titlebar

Is there a way to hide the top title bar in actionbarsherlock while keeping the split action bar visible?

Comment: So, it seems it is inpossible?